# Getting Code 10 error on usb microphone

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, microphone

I have a Editors Keys SL300, which works on another computer. When I plug it into my computer though, I get a message saying "Troubleshoot device" in Devices and Printers. The troubleshoot says that there is a problem with the drivers, which I have reinstalled multiple times. Under Task Manager, it says that it is caused by:

This device cannot start. (Code 10)

{Operation Failed} The requested operation was unsuccessful.

How would I fix this?

I have tried reinstalling drivers, changing USB ports, uninstalling, and disabling the microphone to no avail.

Comment: What version of OS you use on this computer and the other computer?

Comment: Are you using the latest driver from this page: https://www.editorskeys.com/sl300-usb-studio-microphone-extras?

Comment: Hi. yes I have the driver installed. Both computers are Windows 10.